# SlickGrid applying Andrew Childs filter to latest version of master branch

Tags: filter, slickgrid

Let me start by saying I am VERY new to jQuery or any JavaScript programming so please excuse any noob-related mistakes.

I am creating a web app for my company using SlickGrid which will load a different dataset based on the users' role, so my fields will be defined by a dynamic sql query, rather than hard-coded.

I would like to apply Andrew Child's filter on the fork of SlickGrid to the lastest version of the master branch. The filter is displayed on this example: https://github.com/andrewchilds/SlickGrid/blob/master/examples/example15-fork-feature-demo.html

I created a control (using the pager control as a template) to add the filtering header elements. It looks great! Now I just need to make it functional. In following https://github.com/mleibman/SlickGrid/blob/master/examples/example4-model.html it looks like I need to modify this function to loop through the columns, return the filter type and column name, rather than hard-coding the filter type and column name.

```
function myFilter(item, args) {
  if (item["percentComplete"] < args.percentCompleteThreshold) {
    return false;
  }

  if (args.searchString != "" && item["title"].indexOf(args.searchString) == -1) {
    return false;
  }

  return true;
}
```

My questions are:

1. Am I even close to being on the right track?
2. If yes to 1, how do I modify myFilter() and dataView.compileFilter()?

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Welcome to SO!

The filter function (`myFilter` in your case) gets applied to every item (row) in the DataView. If your columns are not hardcoded, you can get a list of columns using `grid.getColumns()`. As an example, take a look at my filter function:

```
function filter(item) {
  for (var columnId in columnFilters) {
    if (columnId !== undefined && columnFilters[columnId] !== "") {
        var c = grid.getColumns()[grid.getColumnIndex(columnId)];
        if(c.field == "...") {
            // return filtered items
        }
        else {
            // return false
        }
    }
  }
return true;
}
```

Here `columnFilters` is an array containing my values to be filtered.

Let me know if you have any questions.

Comment: That's the code from SlickGrid example https://github.com/mleibman/SlickGrid/blob/master/examples/example-header-row.html right? Is that a better way to go than example 4? Example 4 seemed a more elegant solution... btw, thanks for the super quick response!

Comment: That code is what I have on my page. I think it is from one of the SlickGrid examples, but can't remember. I wanted to give you an example of how filtering would work - even with dynamically created columns.

Comment: Thanks ganeshk! it took me a bit to get it, but now it's working! I was making it way more complicated than it needed to be.